# About the spinner's height in Android

Tags: android, spinner

How can I set the height of the spinner? I mean the dropdown items's height.
For I found in SDK12 my spinner will show a long long item list to show the dropdown items.
But it shows to long , how can i set the height?

Answer (score 1):

You can call setDropDownViewResource method and pass corresponding layout, on ArrayAdapter.

In this example im setting simple_spinner_dropdown_item resource which is higher than regular and has a radiobutton. I think you can pass your custom layout to.

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

And in case you are making custom layout, you'll have to declare TextView as root element in order to adapter fill it with text.

Comment: :Thanks zoroz.But what I wanna do is to set the whole items view's height,not the item view.Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: In that case, youll probably need to build a custom spinner popup. Here is one example of how to do it, so see if it can help you.
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could help..

ArrayAdapter yourSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                R.layout.spinner_item, yourItem) {

```
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView,
                    parent);

            convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams p = convertView.getLayoutParams();
            p.height = 100; // set the height
            convertView.setLayoutParams(p);

            return convertView;
        }
    };
```